# Segmentation fault after main returns when building for coverage with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, gcov

I have a C program which compiles and executes fine when I build it without instrumentation flags. However, when I add instrumentation flags (-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage) the same program crashes with a segmentation fault after my main function returns

Has anyone seen this before when building for gcov?

I can see the following stack trace when debugging with gdb in vscode
[image]

Comment: (1) Please don't post screenshots of code, errors, or other textual information. Post as text instead. (2) Run under valgrind and/or address/UB sanitizers.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The stacktrace contains `__tmainCRTstartup` and `msvcrt.dll` which are hints for a Windows system. I am amazed that gcov runs there but AFAIK valgrind does not.

Comment: Probably you have some memory management error in your program that does not show up without instrumentation. If that coverage function crashes, some of their variables are overwritten, presumably. The topmost entry in the callstack `strlen` points to some damaged string buffer.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm running on windows with Msys/MinGW

Comment: Most likely a bug in your program. No way to tell more without seeing the code.

Comment: @thebusybee yea that sounds quite probable, although not fun to debug, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a write beyond array bounds in my program, which was eventually causing segfault later on in the execution